# Mac power save state - what is the state of still running existing process but can't launch new process?

Tags: python, macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I created a a very simple test that launches and close a software I was testing using Python Nose test platform to track down a bug in the start up sequence of the software I was working on.

The test was set up so that it would launch and close about 1,500 times in a singling execution.

A few hours later, I discovered that the test was not able to launch to the software around after 300 iterations.  It was timing out while waiting for the process to start.  As soon as I logged back in, the test started launching the process without any problem and all the tests started passing as well.

This is quite puzzling to me.  I have never seen this behavior.  This never happened on Windows also.

I am wondering if there is a sort of power saving state that Mac was waiting for currently running process to finish and prohibits new process from starting.

I would really appreciate if anybody can shed light on this confusion.

I was running Python 2.7.x on High Sierra.

Comment: Since this seems to be more about a feature of MacOS, rather than a programming issue, you might have better luck on [apple.se]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any state where the system flat out denies new processes while old ones are still running.

However, I can easily imagine a situation in which a process may hang because of some unexpected dependency on e.g. the window server. For example, I once noticed that rsvg-convert, a command-line SVG-to-image converter, running in an SSH session, had different fonts available to it depending on whether I was also simultaneously logged in on the console. This behavior went away when I recompiled the SVG libraries to exclude all references to macOS specific libraries...